# Firebase how to receive notifications after phone REBOOT

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter application using firebase messaging.
It normally receives foreground/opened, on resumed and killed app notifications.

The problem is how to receive notifications after device's reboot ?
I used to do it in pure Android by listening to the BOOT_COMPLETED event in the manifest.xml.

But how to achieve it in Flutter | firebase messaging please ?

Answer (score 2):

`Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)` automatically restarts and resumes the delivery of notifications after a device reboot.

However, to ensure that your notification is delivered immediately after the reboot, you should set the priority of the notification message to `high` using the priority field in the message payload.

Comment: Thanks, used to be an android developer and had to do it myself via a sticky background service on BOOT_COMPLETED ^^
Indeed i had a wierd behavior til now... 
the 1st launch of the app via AndroidStudio did execute FCM and i receive FOREGROUND notifications but when i kill it nothing...
I had to restart the app manually and then notifications survived to the app kill...
Maybe when i tested the device reboot it was on a AndroidStudio launch then...
And ill have a look to the "high" priority you told me about ^^
thanks

Comment: Hum how do you set priority to high via the FCM console ?
I'm on the Notif creation form in 4 steps but nothing like priority ? :(

Comment: You can use this REST API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send to send test notifications via Postman. This way you will be able to add priority field.

Comment: Thanks ! did manage to cofigure FCM Notifications on both android and iOS ^^